# Is there a Chrome flag to disable the notification for progressive web apps (PWA) in Selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, progressive-web-apps

Some web elements are blocked in my mobile Selenium tests because they are blocked by Chromes's PWA notification bar. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Hi! I already tried this and this does not block the PWA notification for me.